# Is the set (0, $\infty$) open?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, infinity

A set is open if it doesn't contain any of its boundary points. I think 0 is a boundary point here and I think it's the only one. So is the set open?

Comment: Yes, it is, and yes, $0$ is its only boundary point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the nail on the head. The only boundary point of $(0,\infty)$ is $0$, which is not in the set. Well done!