# How to prove that $S^+ = \{ (a,\infty) \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \}$ less finer than euclidean?

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck on this problem which seems pretty trivial. I think I need to show that $(a,\infty)$ is open in the usual euclidean topology, but I do not seem to find a solution.

Saying that $(a,\infty) =  \bigcup_{b=0}^\infty(a,b) $ is an acceptable proof?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's your definition of euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, $(a,\infty)$ is open, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534082/is-the-set-0-infty-open).

Comment: If you know that $(a,b)$ is open, then yes. That's acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to remark that $S^+$ is not a topology as $\mathbb{R}$ and the empty set $\emptyset$ are not in $S^+$.

Now let's prove that $\tau=S^+\cup \lbrace \mathbb{R}, \emptyset\rbrace$ is weaker than the euclidean topology $\tau_d$, which is the topology induced by the euclidean distance $d$. 
We claim that every set in $\tau$ is contained $\tau_d$:

Of course $\mathbb{R}\in\tau_d$ and $\emptyset\in \tau_d$. Now let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a,\infty)\in \tau$. We show that $(a, \infty)$ is open with respect to $d$. Indeed, let $x\in (a,\infty)$, then $x\neq a$ and since $d$ is a  metric this implies that $d(a,x)>0$, so
$$ x\in B(x,\frac{d(a,x)}{2})\subset (a,\infty).$$
This shows that $(a, \infty)\in \tau_d$ and concludes the proof of the claim.